# Display image from firebase as large image in push notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-storage, android-glide

I am trying to show an image coming from Firebase as an image in push notification. However whenever i try to show this using the following code, i am getting an exception

```
private void getBitmapAsyncAndDoWork(String imageUrl) {
    final Bitmap[] bitmap = {null};

    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .asBitmap()
            .load(imageUrl)
            .addListener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

                    bitmap[0] = resource;
                    // TODO Do some work: pass this bitmap
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                }
            });
}
```

Following are the exception details

[image: Exception Details]

There is no issue in the image path or access since i am able to show same image on another activity without any issues using below code

```
private void DisplayImage () {
    FirebaseStorage storage = mFirebaseService.getFirebaseStorageInstance();

    getBitmapAsyncAndDoWork(mSpelling.getImagePath());
    // Reference to an image file in Cloud Storage
    StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(mSpelling.getImagePath());

    // ImageView in your Activity
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Glide.with(this).load(storageReference).into(imageView);
}
```

Can someone confirm if i am coding in a right way to display firebase image in notification? Is there any other way to display the image as well?

Comment: That second snippet seems to use FirebaseUI to load the data through the SDK, while the first snippet loads it through the download URL. Both methods of access are quite different. If you log `imageUrl`, what value does it show?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Both methods are different. However i added it to showcase that same image is visible in another activity so there is no issue with URL or access. URL looks like gs://<appname>.appspot.com/abc.PNG.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen .. both the methods are trying to load image via Glide only. First one directly takes the reference of image. Since notification requires it to be converted as BMP, i am using a different way provided by Glide

Comment: A `gs://<appname>.appspot.com/abc.PNG` URL can only be loaded through FirebaseUI, which I dont think your first code snippet is using.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This resolved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your first snippet is trying to load an image through Glide on its own, while the second snippet seems to be [using FirebaseUI to load and display the image](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage#usage).

From the comments we can also see that you're passing a `gs://` URL in the first snippet, which Glide doesn't recognize as it has no built-in support for a `gs://` protocol.

So you'll either have to use the same FirebaseUI approach in your first snippet, or alternatively you can [generate a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) which is a `https://` URL that Glide does have built-in support for.